# After update tableview did not work. Why is this happen?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have interesting problem in my machine. I want to make table view and I did it many times but after the update its not working. Is the making way is changed or what? Can anyone help me?

Here my controller and delegate methods:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let tableView: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView()
    tv.separatorStyle = .none
    tv.allowsSelection = false
    return tv
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    titleOfapp ()
    setupTableView()

}

let sipCellId = "sipCellId"

func titleOfapp () {
    let titleLabelMarka = UILabel()
    titleLabelMarka.textAlignment = .center
    titleLabelMarka.text = "Pak Terminal"
    titleLabelMarka.textColor = UIColor.white
    titleLabelMarka.font = UIFont(name:"Comfortaa-bold", size: 24)
    navigationItem.titleView = titleLabelMarka
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 80.0/255.0, green: 197.0/255.0, blue: 247.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}

func setupTableView() {
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(sipCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: sipCellId)
    view.addSubview(tableView)
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: sipCellId, for: indexPath) as! sipCell
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 80
}



}
```

And here my custom cell code:

```
class sipCell: UITableViewCell {
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


let cellView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    return view
}()

var detailLabel: UILabel = {
    let tf = UILabel()
    tf.text = "mehmet akyol"
    tf.textColor = .black
    tf.font = UIFont(name: "Comfortaa-Bold", size: 13)
    return tf
}()

func setup(){
    addSubview(cellView)
    addSubview(detailLabel)
    cellView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 8, width: 60, height: 55)
    detailLabel.anchor(top: nil, left: cellView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 8, width: 60, height: 40)
    detailLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}

}
```

Comment: What is "not working". What is your actual/expected result?

Comment: What update are you talking about? A migration of your Swift version, or perhaps a new Xcode version? What version were you on initially, and what version are you on now? Please add this to your post.

Comment: @KaiHuppmann I expect to see my table view but I didn't see anything on my simulator.

Comment: You didn't see _anything_?? Is your app starting? Do you see an empty table view?

Comment: @JillevdW xcode 11 and swift 5.1

Comment: @KaiHuppmann I can see my navigation bar but table view didn't appear. Is my code seem correct or not?

Comment: The code I see appears correct to me... (I'd test it before I'd say, it is...), but if the table view does not show at all, the problem is not in the code you posted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to  create constraints for the table

```
view.addSubview(tableView) 
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor) 
])
```

or set a frame